# How can I save a user's actions on react components for future logins on any device?

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, database, user-accounts

I am sort of new to web programming so please bare with me...

Imagine I create a website in using React where you can play three-in-a-row. A logged in user plays and then exits the website and opens it on another device later from the same user account. I assume this would have to be done (and the same goes for even storing the user) by storing the data in a database. What are some common options here? I have a little bit of experience using MySql and php, but have heard there may be other options.

What techniques would be well suited for this type of web application?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to store the data in a database because you want to use it on different machines. As far as the specific database that's depending on the type of data you plan on storing and personal preference. I'd use a noSQL database if possible.